# suggestions of music APIs which provide artists based on a selected genre, album covers, and tracks from the selected album?

Tags: xml, api, uri

I am looking for an an API which will let me query its database via a URI to search for a music artist based on a genre for example rap. I also want the API to give a list of album names and album cover art for a selected artist name or artistID passed in from the URI. The API should also be able to list all the tracks associated with an album title/id also specified from the URI.

In the past I have tried Echonest but they do not provide a way to acquire an album cover art.

I am looking for the result of the URI queries to be displayed in an XML format.

Comment: just to add - you can check musixmatch https://www.mashape.com/musixmatch-com/musixmatch#overview (not sure if they provide genre queries though).

Comment: Have you checked Discogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried allmusic.com?  They have metadata services.

### --UPDATE--

Try out the free music archive, again they have an API but I haven't tested it.
http://freemusicarchive.org/api

And there is always the last.fm APIs.
http://www.last.fm/api

You may find that not all the functionality is possible using a single API, so you may have to use one to get the artists based on genre, another to get cover art etc.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I tried using it and I was unable to request a list of artist names based on a music genre for example Rap. I don't think they provide the functionality for searching for artists based on genre ID.